# creating menu links on a website with both dynamic and static pages

Tags: php, dynamic, menu, static

I have a website that uses mostly dynmaic pages, but as one or two static pages (linked from pages not the menu)

problem is when I go to one of these static pages then use the menu my url gets cought up wrongs

example

```
www.mysite.com/
```

dynamic menu links are 
    ?page=about>
    ?page=contact
    ?page=blog

from     www.mysite.com/?page=blog there is a link where you can read a specific post ths displays on

```
www.mysite.com/article.php
```

if I select the next page from the menu the url it tries to open is

```
www.mysite.com/article.php?page=about
```

how to I force the menu to remove the article.php before trying to access the page?

I have searched everywhere but everything relates to wordpress or jupral, I am building this from scratch to help me learn more on php

thank you

Comment: In your menu change links from `?page=about` etc to `index.php?page=about` and so on.

Comment: Can we see some code? Hard to visualise how you've set this up...

Comment: Have you tried to add the slash? Ie. /?page=about  and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic links should have address beginning with slash:

```
<a href="/?page=about">About</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="?page=about">About</a>
```

In any case, it's better to setup your .httpaccess to read normal urls instead of using GET-requests.

Comment: Thanks all ... I will try all the suggestions one I finish work if the fsiky I will upload the code cheers guys

Comment: thank you, the idea that actually fixed it was the first one from Think Different, cant believe it was so simple, I was thinking I had to write some php code, as the dynamic menu is created from a how to guide copying the start of the links exactly as shown